# SQL : using reserved words as names

Tags: sql, excel

I have excel table with worksheet name **int** and column names  **MainDetailsKey, int** 
( reserved words used as names) . 
When I use following SQL statement
**INSERT INTO [int] (MainDetailsKey, int) VALUES('1', '222')**
I got syntax error exception from Microsoft JET engine
I tried to use 'int' or "int" in the query but in this case I get error that error that object not found
So the question is : what is correct syntax in this case ( for Microsoft JET ) ? 
Your help will be valuable 
Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You need to escape the column name too:

```
INSERT INTO [int] (MainDetailsKey, [int]) VALUES('1', '222')
```

Comment: In this case I got exception :  **"The Microsoft Jet database engine could not find the object 'int'.  Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly."**

Comment: What tables and columns are in your sheet? What's in `GetSchemaTable()`?

Comment: "int","MainDetails" , the table was created by command  **CREATE TABLE int (MainDetailsKey nvarchar , int nvarchar)**  .. For names other than int - insert statement works

Comment: Try escaping the names in the `CREATE TABLE` as well.

Answer (score 1):

in most sql query languages you should use backticks (`) to enclose your column names. In the documentation of Microsoft JET you should find the right characters for JET though...