Google Analyst cert Avocado embedded query
I'm still very new to SQL and making my way through the Google Analyst certification.
I'm getting an unrecognized name error for Small_Bags, Large_Bags Etc.  I'm literally copying the example from the reading and video portion.
SELECT
    Date,
    Region,
    Small_Bags,
    Large_Bags,
    XLarge_Bags,
    Total_bags,
    Small_Bags + Large_Bags + XLarge_Bags AS Total_Bags_Calc
FROM
    `lesson5-399201.avocado_data.avocado_prices` 

I've tried adding tick marks to the column names, replacing the underscores with just a space, even removed the space altogether.  Those are the actual name of the columns.

Check out
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441223/sql-using-reserved-words-as-names?r=SearchResults&s=7%7C74.7001

I had the same issue. Finally figured out
SELECT
    Date,
    Region,
    `Small Bags`,
    `Large Bags`,
    `XLarge Bags`,
    `Total Bags`, 
    (`Small Bags` + `Large Bags` + `XLarge Bags`) AS `Total Bags Calc`
FROM use your project name.AvocadoData.AvocadoPrices`;`


I got the same result as it shows in the exercise [enter image description here][1]

Edit your answer to include a link to the image.
